# dart2js and dart2dart on build

Tags: dart, dart2js

I am trying to build but I have this situation

1. Files in `bin` are server files and don't need to be compiled to js.
2. Server files us `async/await` while client files don't. The server is run with the `--enable-async` VM option.
3. Client files should be treeshaked/minified JS.
4. Client files should ALSO be treeshaked/minified (if possible) to Dart.

Currently I include this in my pubspec.yaml

```
- $dart2js:
    $exclude: bin
```

because I get an error for using `async` on the server. If I include the `async_await` transformer I get even more errors (in fact I had to role back to using `then` on the client).

The real question is how to get efficient server and client dart files, and get efficient client js files out of the build process.

Comment: What do you mean by 4? I guess what you want is dart2dart but this is not supported for the client (less supported than for the server I guess)

Comment: Do you still need the transformer for async/await (client). I never saw/found proper information related to this topic.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am using Angular which contains A LOT of files and I sometimes test the server with Dartium, I'd like treeshaked files. Also, it would be nice if the server files where optimized by dart2dart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use snapshots for server side code. This packs everything into one file and speeds up app startup.

See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/snapshots/ for more details.

I don't have an answer for the other points.